# python pattern match want string after the match

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like `.for $i = 5 .. 13` in the `dict['comment']`. i want get the string after the `$i =`
my output would be like `5 .. 13`

i have tried with

```
if re.match('.for',dict['comment']):
    p=re.match('.for',dict['comment'])
    print '%s' %p.group(0)
```

this match giving only patterns matched string.
i am getting output as

```
.for
.for
.for
```

but i want output after the .for $i =

suggestions please

Comment: Have you looked into *"lookbehind"*?

Comment: No  jonrsharpe. how to use that keyword

Comment: ...what? It's not a [Python keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords), just Google for e.g. *"regex lookbehind"*.

Comment: if re.match('.for',dict['comment']):
            p=re.search('?<=.for',dict['comment'])
            print '%s' %p.group(0)
            

tried with lookbehind got some errors
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 251, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
error: nothing to repeat

Comment: That's unreadable in a comment, [edit] the question to give a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture the text which exists next to =

```
p = re.match(r'.for[^=]*=\s*(.*)',dict['comment'])
if p:
    print '%s' %p.group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the native `string.split()` if the entire string is `.for $i = 5 .. 13`:

```
s = dict['comment']
if '.for' in s:
    output = s.split('=')[1]
#output is then: " 5 .. 13"
```